# Java webservice: use MVC or DAO+managers

Tags: java, web-services, model-view-controller, dao

I'm trying to learn how to develop web-services in java.
Now some tutorials (I'm trying to learn how to do it myself without using a framework) use the MVC pattern and expose the class to create a WSDD file etc., other tutorials go for a DAO + managers.

Now I haven't been able to find an article discussing the differences (asking for up and downsides is probably a bit too simplistic), so I was wondering if anyone here had some insights and maybe some recommended reading (be it books or tutorials on sites) since some sites are a bit contradictory.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAO + managers is simply how you would implement the model part of your MVC design.

A DAO gives you access to your data store and the DAO, the managers, and all the logic are what make up your model.

The view and controller and then made up of other components and talk to the model to get information from your data store.

WSDD files simply chain these parts together.

You should be able to use both pattern together.